"the one" VS "someone" — { vocative = marking THE ONE addressed } VS { vocative = marking SOMEONE addressed }
merriam-webster.com:
(1) The adjective "vocative" can mean "marking the one addressed". (such as "mother" in "mother, come here")
my variant:
(2) The adjective "vocative" can mean "marking someone addressed".
I think (1) = (2).
Am I right?
If not, then what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

May I respectfully suggest that you rewrite this question, because, as I understand it, you are really asking "What is the difference between the one and someone?" The information about vocative etc. just seems irrelevant.

@PeterJennings I agree that the information about vocative is irrelevant but also I think it's better to write examples in the headlines in order that people see the context. The word "vocative" is part of the example. That is, I don't know how to rewrite the headline, complying with both things.

(3) The adjective "vocative" can mean marking [some]one who is addressed. But isn't it just really asking What is the difference between the one and [some] one?


marking the one addressed


marking someone addressed

When a person (someone) is addressed, he becomes unique and is now the one.     Hence the OP’s second version (using someone) is equivalent to the first (using the one).

Briefly, the one refers to a specific individual, in your case you are talking to "mother"
someone refers to any individual it might be your mother, it might be a complete stranger.
